# Recommendations for video editing + screen capturing software

Tags: screen-capture, video-editing

I'd like to make a video demo of my upcoming web application. Requirements include:

1. Being able to have a sound track (probably just an mp3)
2. Being able to 'film' screen work and chop it to bits and pieces to be embedded in the movie
3. Having text, photo effects, fade in-out, constant motion (similar to mac screen saver slide show) etc - nothing too fancy.
4. "Timeline" editor where I can combine all those elements and time them perfectly
5. HD output with formats I can export later to Vimeo or YouTube.

I you have recommendations to video editing/video screen capturing i'd be happy to hear those. I've never done that before, but I do have lots of graphics experience and a good eye. Should be an interesting attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **[ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/overview.htm) ($99)**

It's a little pricey, but very powerful screen capture utility. You can do the effects/transitions inside, or export and edit it Final Cut or iMovie.

This is an [example](http://youtu.be/UWBIwsBcmz0?hd=1) clip I did a while ago with ScreenFlow and Final Cut.