# Is there any free screencasting software?

Tags: software-recommendation, screen-capture, recording

I am searching for an OK and free screencasting app to finally start LP-ing.
The app doesn't have to record sound because I can do that sort of stuff with Audacity. Recently  tried out "Copernicus", a screencasting app; I set the frame rate to 30, hoping for a good result, but it didn't turn out that well. In fact, it was horrible, the 8 second video I captured using this software turned out to have 2 frames per second.

If you happen to know of any good, free software for screencasting, please post some links.

Comment: similar: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16834/recommendations-for-video-editing-screen-capturing-software

Answer (score 12):

I don't do a lot of LPs, but the last time I did I used QuickTime Player.app (Quicktime Player X); you'll find it in /Applications. To record your screen, select File > New Screen Recording.

The results were pretty good; recording Minecraft 1.7.3 gameplay on an about a year and a half old MBP, but I have a lot of RAM, so that certainly helps.

**Edit:**

It's worth noting that QuickTime Player X does not support loopback sound; meaning that the only sound recorded will be from the microphone, or virtual sound device providing loopback sound.

This may or may not be a good thing, depending on what you are doing.

Comment: +1 for QuickTime. Most of my screen-casts are simple and lasts five minutes or less. In this case, QuickTime works well.

Comment: Ack! I was going to say Jing and Quicktime. Looks like I was beaten to it...

Comment: I also learned to like QuickTime (note that I previously used screenr). In combination with [Audio Hijack](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) you can record microphone & application sounds all together nicely.

Answer (score 2):

### [Jing](http://www.techsmith.com/jing/)

by TechSmith. There's a free version and a paid Pro version.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Screenr](http://screenr.com)
It allows to create great screencasts and share them online instantly.

It requires Java to be installed. For the first time you need to accept their Java Plugin to launch the Screen Recorder.
I am using it for several small screencasts, because it just works.

Comment: Note that it requires Java.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give [Debut](http://www.nchsoftware.com/capture/index.html) a try which (according to their website) offers screen recording and a lot of additional features. They also provide a free version for home use so you can do a test run without having to invest a lot of money.